# Programatically load title of a views page by its machine name

Tags: views, theming

I would like to use the current title of a very specific views page in another template. Instead of just *manually* copying it and in order to stay flexible and always up to date, I would like to programatically load and insert it.

If my views page has machine name `views_page`, how do I programatically load its current title into a string?

Comment: what do you mean "another template"?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work:

Load the View and get the display title:

```
$view = views_get_view('views_page');
print $view->display['page_1']->display_options['title'];
```

Note: Change 'page_1' to the name of your display.

You can also get the page title from the path:

```
$item = menu_get_item(drupal_get_normal_path('path/to/page'));
print $item['title'];
```